# Sci-fi Show with Tech Magic/Psychic Powers

Tags: story-identification, tv, magic, soft-sci-fi

The show was on in the late 90's or early 00's. It may have been re-runs at that point though. It was on the SciFi channel. It was live action.

I don't remember much of the plot, but it involved characters on a larger ship doing some kind of adventures. I do remember that there was a character who was in an order of tech mages - people who could manipulate technology with magic or psychic powers or something?

Comment: Was this live-action or animated? Also, can you describe any of the characters (age, sex, hair colour, etc)?

Comment: _"The show was on in the late 90's or early 20's."_ Not to nitpick, but we are _currently_ in the early 20's.  I suspect you mean the early 00's or "aughts". :)

Comment: Voltron Legendary Defenders? A few episodes covered something much like this.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Possibly [Crusade](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0149437/), a Babylon 5 spin-off?  One of the characters is a [techno-mage](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Techno-mage) named [Galen](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0149437/characters/nm0940974?ref_=tt_cl_c_5), [large ship](https://babylon5.fandom.com/wiki/Excalibur), adventures, 1999.

Comment: Bablyon 5 was also my first thought. It might be the main series if the OP misremembers the space station as a large ship.

Comment: That's exactly it, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

There was an episode of Babylon5 that had a technomage visit the station.

Molllari insults him, and gets "hexed" as punishment.

Comment: Youtube URL of a scene from that episode: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZjToVZTqCbw